# CTAS vs INSERT/SELECT to empty columnar table on Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure-synapse

I am running a series of tests to understand the throughput per DWU.  I have eight (8) scenarios varying the ETL approach (CTAS vs INSERT/SELECT), varying the input table type (heap vs columnar), and varying the output table type (heap vs columnar).

Unexpectedly, using a columnar input table, writing to a columnar output table, using either INSERT/SELECT or CTAS yielded the same throughput (8,100 rows per second per DWU).

Why would there not be some penalty associated with "full logging" of the INSERT/SELECT construct?

Givens:

- DWU = 600
- table 17 columns with 1.33B rows
- target table empty
  beforehand

**INSERT/SELECT Script:**

```
CREATE TABLE
     etl_schema_name.fact_table_benchmark_testing
     (
     column_1               INTEGER           NOT NULL
    ,column_2              INTEGER           NOT NULL
    ,column_3                SMALLINT          NOT NULL
    ,column_4                SMALLINT          NOT NULL
    ,column_5               INTEGER           NOT NULL
    ,column_6               DECIMAL(9,4)      NOT NULL
    ,column_7              DECIMAL(9,2)      NOT NULL
    ,column_8       SMALLINT          NOT NULL
    ,column_9             CHAR(1)           NOT NULL
    ,column_10              SMALLINT          NOT NULL
    ,column_11            DECIMAL(9,2)      NOT NULL
    ,column_12            DECIMAL(9,2)      NOT NULL
    ,column_13            DECIMAL(9,2)      NOT NULL
    ,column_14            DECIMAL(9,2)      NOT NULL
    ,column_15            DECIMAL(9,2)      NOT NULL
    ,column_16            DECIMAL(9,2)      NOT NULL
    ,column_17            DECIMAL(9,2)      NOT NULL
     )
WITH
     (
      DISTRIBUTION = HASH ( column_2 )
     )
;
GO

insert into
     etl_schema_name.fact_table_benchmark_testing
     (
     column_1
    ,column_2
    ,column_3
    ,column_4
    ,column_5
    ,column_6
    ,column_7
    ,column_8
    ,column_9
    ,column_10
    ,column_11
    ,column_12
    ,column_13
    ,column_14
    ,column_15
    ,column_16
    ,column_17
     )
select
     column_1
    ,column_2
    ,column_3
    ,column_4
    ,column_5
    ,column_6
    ,column_7
    ,column_8
    ,column_9
    ,column_10
    ,column_11
    ,column_12
    ,column_13
    ,column_14
    ,column_15
    ,column_16
    ,column_17
FROM
     production_schema_name.fact_table
;
GO
```

**CTAS Script**

```
CREATE TABLE
     etl_schema_name.fact_table_benchmark_testing_2
WITH
     (
      DISTRIBUTION = HASH ( column_2 )
     )
as
select
     column_1
    ,column_2
    ,column_3
    ,column_4
    ,column_5
    ,column_6
    ,column_7
    ,column_8
    ,column_9
    ,column_10
    ,column_11
    ,column_12
    ,column_13
    ,column_14
    ,column_15
    ,column_16
    ,column_17
FROM
     production_schema_name.fact_table

;
GO
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

INSERT...SELECT is not necessarily fully logged in SQLDW. Have you had a chance to review the following article?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-best-practices-transactions